# Print if numbers of list are even or odd

Tags: python

```
listofNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for number in listofNumbers:
    print  (number),
if (number % 2 ==0):
    print (" is even")
else :
    print(" is odd")

print("All done.")
```

I wanted my codes to print 1,2,3,4,5,6 and specific if each is even or odd, but it only brings the figures, no remarks,

Comment: Fix your indentation. Your `if` must be inside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first print statement - on L3. It is simply printing through the array right now in a loop. Remove line 3 or comment it out, transform number to str type in print statement, and it will do as you wish.

```
listofNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for number in listofNumbers:
    if (number % 2 == 0):
        print (str(number) + " is even")
    else:
        print(str(number) + " is odd")

print("All done.")
```

Answer (score -1):

The if/else needs to be within the for loop:

```
listofNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for number in listofNumbers:
    print(number, end="" )
    if (number % 2 ==0):
        print(" is even")
    else :
        print(" is odd")
print("All done.")
```

Comment: Improvements were implemented!